# Android Toolbar Items not showing?

Tags: android, toolbar, menuitem, appbar

I'm trying to create a Toolbar with the android.support.v7.widget.toolbar but when i try t add an item, it will not show on the toolbar:

Toolbar in activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

main_activity:
on the onCreate:

```
Toolbar my_tbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(my_tbar);
```

out of onCreate:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

res/menu/main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
    android:title="RefreshButton"
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh_icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />

</menu>
```

the `refresh_icon` is created by me because in the `@drawable/`i didn't found the `ic_menu_refresh`

Why the button is not shown?

Thank you

Comment: have you this bunch of code public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not showing because your not infalting the menu layout. Before calling `onOptionsItemSelected()` you need to inflate the layout like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

just add this method in your activity, and it will work fine.

Comment: Funny, Google left this out of the developers guide.